# antlr reading grammar tokens from file

Tags: antlr, antlr4, antlr3, antlrworks, antlrv3ide

I want to parse the sentence `"i am looking for a java developer"`. The output I need is `language=java.`

I created a grammar file as follows.

```
grammar Job;

eval returns [String value]
    :    output=jobExp { $value = $output.text;}
    ;
jobExp returns [String value]
    :    ind=indro whitespace var1=language ' developer'  {$value = $var1.text;}
    ;

indro
    :
    'i am looking for a' |   'i am searching for a'
    ;

language :
    'java' | 'python' | 'cpp'
    ;

whitespace :
    (' '|'\t')+
    ;
```

Here, in rule `language` i am hard-coding a set of languages inside the grammar file itself. Is it possible to read the languages from a file and process the grammar accordingly ?
Input file should be like this

languages.txt

```
 java
 python
 cpp
```

I am using `antlr 4.5.1-1`.

Comment: why would you want to do this in the grammar? why not parse `language` (in the example a single token as a string) and let the programme use the input file to check, if the language is supported or not? together with an action you can ensure this check from within your grammar.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure if this completely satisfies your question, but look into Composite Grammars:

https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Composite+Grammars

If you really need it to be in a file, consider creating a processing/build step from languages.txt to languages.grammar, and use languages.grammar as Composite.